# How to re-render vue component when vuex state change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet, vue-component, vuex

I want to create a component like a control layer to change the basemap of the leaflet. But I don't want to use `L.control.layers`. So, I made a sidebar component that have options to change the basemap.

I use vuejs and to organize the data I use vuex.
This is my code

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        satellite: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        dark: 'https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png',
        osm: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        topography: 'https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        baseMap: 'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}'
    },
    getters: {
        baseMap: state => state.baseMap
    },
    actions: {
        changeBaseMap({ commit }, base) {
            commit("CHANGE_BASE_MAP", base);
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        CHANGE_BASE_MAP(state, base) {
            state.baseMap = base
        }
    },
})
```

The sidebar component to change the value of the `baseMap`is worked. But, the leaflet component doesn't change when `baseMap` state changes, it just changes the value of `baseMap` not the leaflet component.

This is my Map component, I use `computed` to access `baseMap` value when `state` changes

```
<template>
    <div id="container" >
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div> 
</template>

<script>
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";

export default {
    name: "Map",
    data() {
        return {
            center: [-0.789275,113.921327],
            zoom: 5,
            map: null
        };
    },
    computed: {
        baseMap: function () {
            return this.$store.getters.baseMap
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setupLeafletMap () {
            this.map = L.map("map").setView(this.center, this.zoom);
            var tilelayer = L.tileLayer(this.baseMap)
            tilelayer.addTo(this.map)
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.setupLeafletMap();
    }
};
</script>
```

I try to call `baseMap` value inside the `<div>` tag, and when state changes, it changes. But the leaflet base layer doesn't change

```
<div id="map">{{ baseMap }}</div>
```

I've been looking for a solution but I'm still confused. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: As far es I know this happens because `baseMap` is reactive, but that doesn´t affect your 'setupLeafletMap' function. Actually you maybe need to call that function in every state change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should

```
 watch: {
        baseMap () {
            this.setupLeafletMap()
        }
    },
```